# Adding a dll reference with a c# program to another project

Tags: c#

I want to make an c# program that can automaticly add [this](https://github.com/Alex31TheDev/BasicFuntionality) dll to an specified c# project name/path. I need that functinality to make adding my dll to an project really easy(and thats all about my dll to make things simpl)

Is this even possible?
You can send answers that use python and c# togheter.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: It will be most easy if you put the library in a Nuget package and then use the Nuget package manager from inside Visual Studio. That's what they exist for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to code an application for that, .NET already has a mechanism for that: it's called a **Nuget Package**.

Think of it as an installer for assemblies into a project.

You can start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget) reading about it.

Comment: But I want an kinda framework manager that can automaticly add the refrence.